# What does "Reverse Continue" do in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I noticed that VS2019 Professional Edition has a `Reverse Continue` button. So I assumed it makes a step back to the previous line when debugging, but it remains grayed out.

So what does `Reverse Continue` button do in Visual Studio 2019?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might be IntelliTrace? You may not have it enabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-using-intellitrace?view=vs-2019

Comment: By the way, is the tooltip "reverse continue"? It also could just be a navigate-back button.

Comment: @Blorgbeard It's a Professional Edition, so the feature is not even present.  And there is no Tooltip on it.  Or maybe it comes on when the button is active, but it never gets turned on.

Comment: OK. I don't have VS installed anymore, so I can't really check.. but what makes you think it's a "reverse continue" button if there's no tooltip?

Comment: @Blorgbeardisout it's called "Reverse Continue" in the Add Or Remove Buttons menu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This button appears to be related to the Time Travel Debugging (TTD) feature available in VS 2019 Enterprise. TTD allows the developer to take a snapshot during a debugging session, in which every line of code executed during the session is recorded. The Reverse Continue button can be used to "play" these lines of code in reverse.

For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-live-azure-virtual-machines-time-travel-debugging?view=vs-2019.

I don't know why this button is visible in VS 2019 Professional, when the only documentation I could find on it requires VS 2019 Enterprise.